# libGDX SpriteBatch reuse

Tags: java, libgdx, spritebatch

Using libGDX, sprites or simply texture regions must be inserted into the batch for drawing:

```
void render()
{
    batch.begin();

    batch.draw(...);

    batch.end();
}
```

Is the VBO being uploaded to the GPU in every frame?
Is there a way to reuse the batch once any of the data changed?

Answer (score 2):

LibGDX already binds the textures for you under the hood: [Texture.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.java)

For 99% of cases you can just let the SpriteBatch draw everything for you; it does so with very good efficiency. I would suggest referring to the [extensive documentation on the wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch,-Textureregions,-and-Sprites).

Additionally, if you use the [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets), textures will be re-bound even after an OpenGL context loss.

Regarding "re-using" the batch, the same SpriteBatch can render every frame as long as you are calling begin() and end(). You shouldn't create more than one SpriteBatch.

Comment: My question was about not changing the vertex buffer in every frame, like a static batch which gets filled once and draws many frames. I agree that SpriteBatch class draws stuff efficiently, only changing states when needed and this way minimizing draw calls. Sorry if the question is not clear.

Comment: Look into the SpriteCache class rather than SpriteBatch.  It allows you to collect texture data once and re-use it.